# efficient numpy.roll before numpy.sum() or mean()

Tags: python, numpy

I have several (order of 1000) 3D-arrays of shape (1000, 800, 1024) I want to study. I need to calculate the mean along axis=0, but before I can do that, I have to roll the data along axis 2, until it is 'in the right place'.

This sounds strange, so I'll try to explain. The 1D-sub-array of shape (1024,) is data from a physical ring buffer. The ring buffer is read out in different possitions, which I know. So I have several arrays `pos` of shape (1000, 800). Telling me in what position the ring buffer was read out. And my 3D-arrays `data` of shape (1000, 800, 1024) that I need to roll according to `pos`.

Only after the rolling .. the 3D arrays are meaningful for me and I can start analysing them.
In C one can write code which is doing this pretty simple so I wonder if I can kind of, 'tell' the numpy mean() or sum() routines they should start at different indices and 'roll around' at the end of the 1D-subarray.

What I currently do is this:

```
rolled = np.zeros_like(data) # shape (1000, 800, 1024)
for a in range(rolled.shape[0]):
    for b in range(rolled.shape[1]):
        rolled[a,b] = np.roll(data[a,b], pos[a,b])
```

This takes ~60sec 
And then I do e.g:

```
m = rolled.mean(axis=0)
s = rolled.std(axis=0)
```

Which only takes 15sec or so.

My point is, that making the rolled copy takes a lot of space and time (okay I could save space by writing the rolled stuff back into `data`), while there is definitely a way (in C) to implement this averaging and rolling in one loop, therefor saving a lot of time.
My question is ... if there is a way to do something similar with numpy?

Comment: there already is a [`numpy.roll`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.roll.html). doesn't fit your calculations?

Comment: @behzad.nouri I edited my question. I already use np.roll, but I actually don't need the rolled data, but rather want mean() and std() to behave a little 'different' .. :-) 
I guess there is no way to do this quicker with Python ... maybe using inline C is the answer ...

Comment: I doubt doing the averaging and so on in a single loop is a lot faster, since it would mess with your cache coherency; reorganizing the data once is probably fastest. Indeed the memory overhead is superfluous, but you might save a little by writing a C-extension to optimize the rolling, and eliminate the python loops.  Either way you are dealing with terrabytes of data, so be prepared to wait, or learn how to use one of the many C extensions method for python.

Comment: Of course if you can fuse all your reduction operations in a single loop, that could save quite some time, and it would also mean there is no point rolling the data separately first. But yeah then you are looking at a C-extension for sure. Have you looked at numba?

Comment: Any chance you can roll the 1024-long array when you read it from the circular buffer, before putting it in `data`? This might hide the 60 sec delay, especially if you have to wait for the circular buffer to have more available data anyway.

Answer (score 11):

I got bored and wrote your function in Cython. It runs about 10x faster than the code you posted, without allocating an intermediate array.

```
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np
cimport cython
from libc.math cimport sqrt

@cython.boundscheck(False)
@cython.wraparound(False)
@cython.nonecheck(False)
@cython.cdivision(True)
def rolled_mean_std(double[:,:,::1] data, int[:,::1] pos):
  cdef Py_ssize_t s1,s2,s3,a,b,c
  s1 = data.shape[0]
  s2 = data.shape[1]
  s3 = data.shape[2]
  cdef double[:,::1] sums = np.zeros((s2,s3))
  cdef double[:,::1] sumsq = np.zeros((s2,s3))
  cdef double d
  cdef int p
  # Compute sums and sum-of-squares.
  for a in range(s1):
    for b in range(s2):
      p = pos[a,b]
      for c in range(s3):
        d = data[a,b,(c+s3-p)%s3]
        sums[b,c] += d
        sumsq[b,c] += d * d
  # Calculate mean + std in place.
  for b in range(s2):
    for c in range(s3):
      d = sums[b,c]
      sums[b,c] /= s1
      sumsq[b,c] = sqrt((s1*sumsq[b,c] - (d*d)))/s1
  return sums, sumsq
```

Note that this uses the [Naive mean+stdv algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithms_for_calculating_variance), so you might run into floating point accuracy errors. My tests didn't show much of an effect, though.

Comment: Wow! thanks you @perimosocordiae. Very kind of you. I definitly should look more into Cython. However I can't mark your post as the answer, since it does not really hit the point...

Comment: I understand. :-) Unfortunately, I think the correct answer is "you can't".